# SignalR Cross Domain

Tags: c#, nginx, cors, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I can see this question has been asked many times. Yet all the solutuions are years old and do not work with DotNet 6.0.

I have a SignalR js client.  It is rendered from Server A.  I have my signalR server on Server B.  It is on a fixed IP address.

I try to call from the client this server...

```
socket= new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://X.X.X.X/MyHub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
```

But I get cors error:

[image]

Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error

my servers are ubuntu 20. The web server is written in asp.net C# ver 6.0

In server B I have in program:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policyBuilder =>
{
    policyBuilder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true); // allow any origin 
}));
```

Both servers are https.

In my nginx config file I have this:

```
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
    location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
#
# Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
#
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
#
# Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
#
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-  Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-        Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }
}
```

which I got from here:

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

```
upstream websocketCloud {
  server 127.0.0.1:9771;
}
```

Comment: Show us the **actual** HTTP requests and responses from the CORS negotiation, including all headers - not just a uselessly cropped Chrome DevTools screenshot.

Comment: Your nginx configuration doesn't make any references to WebSockets or SSE

Comment: @Dai I am not usnig websockets amd my configuration works  for the Server A that uses the same socket but on that Server A. And the socket has already been defined. It is a CORs issue not a socket one

Comment: I appreciate that my comment-reply comes across as rude.

Comment: ...if you're not using WebSockets, then how are you expecting SignalR to work? (SignalR-for-ASP.NET-Core dropped support for the legacy Long-Polling transport, [now it only supports WebSockets and/or SSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-8.0))

Comment: It's extremely difficult to effectively diagnose CORS issues without seeing all request and response headers from the exchange - until and unless you post that data there's not much that I, or anyone else, can do other than speculate.

Comment: @dai not immature just grumpy since I just woken up. Sorry. I have re-editied

Comment: @dai re:It's extremely difficult point taken. I will try and but more comprehensive in the future. I am still using net 6.0 as when I deployed with .net 7 to a ubuntu server and my raspberry pi Debian I can no longer debug (breakpoints are not hit) and could not resolve. I will migrate to net 8 when I get ahead and see what happens.  I used to prefer websockets so wil be good to go back to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use below cors settings.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));
```

**Reason**

You are using `AllowAnyOrigin()` and `SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)` together, and if credentials (such as cookies) are enabled in the CORS  configuration and you try to use the `.AllowAnyOrigin()` method, you will encounter cross-domain issues.

I know my sample code not security, if it work, you can using below code. It will be safe.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
{
    policy
        .WithOrigins("Your A site") 
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple. Worked straight away!  Life Saver!!